# In spring security, use basic-auth per Request Method

Tags: java, spring-security

Lets say i have this web security config and the url for posting and getting all customers is the same:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/customers/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Is there any way i can add security to POST requests to customers only, while allowing GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the matcher:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/customers/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")

            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/customers/**")
            .permitAll()

            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```